# how can Android App A bring front the form of Android B by the click of a Button from Android A

Tags: android, android-layout, tcplistener

I want to do a POC in which I want to bring up a form display of Android app B by clicking a button from Android App A i.e it must bring up/bring the form or Activity or a  display of Android App B to the front and after that when user is Clicking a button say "minimize" it  must minimize the display (or go back to forground )of Android app B and bring back the display of Android app A (Both Android  app A and B will be on the same device)

I am not looking a solution to open the App B but purely to bring up the form of Android app  B assuming if the Android B app is running in the background on the same device

[image]

Comment: You'd typically do this through [Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters).  App B would already have to have defined an intent in order for you to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

Use intent from APP "A"

`Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("App B packagename");
startActivity(launchIntent);`

for minimizing App B and come again to App A

`Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("App A packagename");
startActivity(launchIntent);`

[check app is running on background or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43779914/9213105)